# hide div, two dynamic statuses javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble combining actions when clicking the button in javascript, I would like to filter the divs hiding according to the user's click.

are two filters day and status

if he clicks on the day he can match the status being that there are five buttons for days and five different statuses that can be combined between them

the way I managed to hide the dividends, only when I click on the conflict status.

**Ex:**

**click on the "visibility semana" button on Filter 1**
Result = ok, no 2

**after clicking on "visibility no" in Filter 2**
Result = ok, no

**the correct would be**
Result = no 2

```
<div> <h1>Filter 1 </h1> 

       <button id="btnhoje" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose _btn-visible">
            <i class="material-icons icon">visibility</i>
            <span>Hoje</span>
        </button>
        <button id="btnsemana" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose _btn-visible">
            <i class="material-icons icon">visibility</i>
            <span>Semana</span>
        </button>
</div>
<div> <h1>Filter 2 </h1> 
        <button id="btnok" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose _btn-visible">
            <i class="material-icons icon">visibility</i>
            <span>ok</span>
        </button>
        <button id="btnno" class="btn btn-fill btn-rose _btn-visible">
            <i class="material-icons icon">visibility</i>
            <span>no</span>
        </button>
</div>

<div> <h1>Result </h1> 
<div class="hoje ok">ok</div>
<div class="semana no">no</div>
<div class="hoje no">no 2</div>
</div>
```

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnhoje").on("click", function ( eve ) {
                    $(".hoje").toggle("slow");
                    let b_isVisible = this.classList.contains("_btn-hoje")
                      , s_buttontext
                      , s_text
                      ;

                    if (b_isVisible) {

                        s_text          = 'visibility';
                        this.classList.remove("_btn-hoje");
                    } else {

                        s_text          = 'visibility_off';
                        this.classList.add("_btn-hoje");
                    }                      
                    // $("span", this).text(s_buttontext);
                    $("i", this).text(s_text);
                    $(this).val(s_buttontext);
                });
            }); 

   $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnsemana").on("click", function ( eve ) {
                    $(".semana").toggle("slow");
                    let b_isVisible = this.classList.contains("_btn-semana")
                      , s_buttontext
                      , s_text
                      ;

                    if (b_isVisible) {

                        s_text          = 'visibility';
                        this.classList.remove("_btn-semana");
                    } else {

                        s_text          = 'visibility_off';
                        this.classList.add("_btn-semana");
                    }                      
                    // $("span", this).text(s_buttontext);
                    $("i", this).text(s_text);
                    $(this).val(s_buttontext);
                });
            }); 

   $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnok").on("click", function ( eve ) {
                    $(".ok").toggle("slow");
                    let b_isVisible = this.classList.contains("_btn-ok")
                      , s_buttontext
                      , s_text
                      ;

                    if (b_isVisible) {
                        // s_buttontext    = 'Hoje';
                        s_text          = 'visibility';
                        this.classList.remove("_btn-ok");
                    } else {
                       // s_buttontext    = 'Hoje';
                        s_text          = 'visibility_off';
                        this.classList.add("_btn-ok");
                    }                      
                    // $("span", this).text(s_buttontext);
                    $("i", this).text(s_text);
                    $(this).val(s_buttontext);
                });
            }); 


   $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnno").on("click", function ( eve ) {
                    $(".no").toggle("slow");
                    let b_isVisible = this.classList.contains("_btn-no")
                      , s_buttontext
                      , s_text
                      ;

                    if (b_isVisible) {
                        // s_buttontext    = 'Hoje';
                        s_text          = 'visibility';
                        this.classList.remove("_btn-no");
                    } else {
                       // s_buttontext    = 'Hoje';
                        s_text          = 'visibility_off';
                        this.classList.add("_btn-no");
                    }                      
                    // $("span", this).text(s_buttontext);
                    $("i", this).text(s_text);
                    $(this).val(s_buttontext);
                });
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/queiroz_gabriel/s0o297dp/8/

Comment: Hello, Welcome to stackoveflow, it is always good to replicate the situation online like this link,
https://jsfiddle.net/itbaran/nsu7wtam/
Anyway, when I have created this sample it seems your question is not clear, accordingly, so it's better to improve your question with some clarification!

Comment: I really can't understand what are you trying to do exactly. Do you want to toggle visibility of text element statuses when corresponding days are clicked?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/queiroz_gabriel/s0o297dp/8/

Comment: click on the "visibility Semana" button on Filter 1
Result = ok, no 2

after clicking on "visibility no" in Filter 2
Result = ok, no

the correct would be
Result = no 2